# Flutter: Error after turning off internet connection - "Error while applying io.flutter.console.FlutterConsoleFilter@70f92821 to 'W/zzajf ( 5265)"

Tags: error-handling, flutter, disconnection

I use Firestore for my Flutter app.

When I disable internet connection on emulator, this error appears on the console:

```
V/NativeCrypto( 6278): Read error: ssl=0xa4621708: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
W/zzaeo   ( 6278): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
V/NativeCrypto( 6278): Write error: ssl=0xa4621708: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
V/NativeCrypto( 6278): Write error: ssl=0xa4621708: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
W/zzajf   ( 6278): Failed closing connection
W/zzajf   ( 6278): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0xa4621708: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.write(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):2)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLOutputStream.write(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzapc.write(Unknown Source:36)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzaot.write(Unknown Source:46)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzapf.close(Unknown Source:24)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzaku.close(Unknown Source:6)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzaim.run(Unknown Source:14)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzahi.run(Unknown Source:13)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
W/zzajf   ( 6278):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/zzaeo   ( 6278): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/zzaeo   ( 6278): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/zzaeo   ( 6278): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
```

However, the app keeps running as usual after disconnection. I read about similar errors, and people say that it's a normal behavior and the error should be handled only if it is necessary to retry to make a connection.

Is that a normal behavior? Or if not, how should I handle it?

Comment: I was getting this error, did not notice that my device was disconnected. Thanks to your question, now I know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a network check before calling your function for Firestore to avoid this exception.
To check the network connectivity, I'll recommend you to use [Connectivity](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity) package. Its pretty simple to use and works for both Android and iOS.

Comment: Note that you should not be using the current network status for deciding whether you can reliably make a network connection. Always guard your app code against timeouts and errors that might come from the network layer.